# tfs merge missing changeset yet they were merged

Tags: version-control, tfs, merge, branch

I'm seeing some strange behavior from TFS and I'm trying to understand what it is telling me.

I have two branches, `$/Project/trunk` and `$/Project/master`  (trunk is branched from master)

A merge was done this way, merging everything from trunk to master.

`tf merge $/Project/trunk $/Project/master /recursive`

Example `tf history $/Project/trunk /recursive`

```
12        Dev C         10/1/2015  message
11        Dev B         10/1/2015  message
10        Dev A         9/30/2015  message
```

Yet, `tf merges $/Project/trunk $/Project/master /recursive` shows

```
Changeset Merged in Changeset Author                           Date
--------- ------------------- -------------------------------- ----------
       10                 526 Dev A                           10/15/2015
       12                 526 Dev A                           10/15/2015
```

So what happened to changeset 11 ???
- It was clearly merged (`tf merge /candidate` does **not** show it).
- It is clearly in the history of trunk

Yet it does not show as merged in the merge tracking?  Why?

BTW: I'm using TFS 2013, with tf.exe from Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 1):

Clear the TFS Client cache (The cache folder locate in C:\Documents and Settings[USER]\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache on your development machine), and then double check if changeset 11 still exist in trunk. By the way, what is the version of the TFS you are using?

Comment: I found two cache folders in AppData\Local.  I deleted both and tried again,  No effect.  I updated the question.

Comment: Then if you merge the changeset 11 to master via command: 
tf merge /version:11~11 $/Project/trunk $/Project/master /recursive, what happens?

Comment: Remarkably, merging 11 manually as you specified did mark it as merged (didn't change any files, as expected since 11 was already merged).  Can it possibly be that I will have to merge one at a time to convince TFS to do proper merge tracking?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, as soon as you run the tf merge command, the changes for these merged change set will be placed in the "Pending Changes" of master. The only thing you need to do to reflect the result in TFVC Server is check in all these changes.

Comment: I did check in the change.  11 is now marked as merged, however a different changeset that was marked as merged is now not marked as merged.  I simply cannot follow the process that TFS uses for merge tracking.

Comment: @karoberts, is there any common point between changeset 11 and that different changeset? And any steps that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Vicky, I'm not really sure.  I've simplified things a bit for the question.  In reality there was more than just 11, there were about 50 "missing" changesets which I manually marked as merged as recommended above by Eddie.  After that there are now 50ish more that became unmarked.  More experimentation has shown me that it has to do with renames.  Renames seem to propagate across branches even before you merge them.  Seems odd.